Mutex Issues in IL2CPP
In IL2CPP, I'm unable to use Mutex and receive an error message saying the method cannot be found.
Is there any way to solve this, or are there any alternative solutions?
I found a post that says IL2CPP cannot use Mutex, it has to be Mono. Is there any way to use it in IL2CPP?
If not using IL2CPP, the effects in Awake and Start are different, and the effects integrated into the project are also different. How can I solve this problem?
